# Clear cell when corresponding cell updates

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating an Excel spreadsheet that requires a name (column C) to correlate with a status (column E). As the schedule and priority is changed, the active name may change and so the status must clear any time the name changes. Column C is data pulled from a separate spreadsheet with `VLOOKUP`.

I have little to no experience with VBA but this is what I have pieced together from research. It works if data in column C is not linked to another cell but column C needs to contain

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A4&"-"&1,'[Control.xlsx]Input'!$BF$3:$BI$152,3,FALSE),"")
```

and so it is not working.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Target, Me.Range("F4")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    On Error GoTo Finalize
    Range("E4").ClearContents
Finalize:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Changes in the result of formulas do not trigger the `Change` event.

Comment: It's a **column** - not a "collum" ....

Answer (score 1):

Try this to your posted sub:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim changedCell As Range

' Check if the changed cells are in column C
If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Columns("C")) Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False ' Disable events to prevent infinite loop

    ' Loop through each changed cell in column C
    For Each changedCell In Intersect(Target, Me.Columns("C"))
        ' Get the corresponding row in column E and clear the content
        Me.Cells(changedCell.Row, "E").ClearContents
    Next changedCell

    Application.EnableEvents = True ' Enable events back
End If
```

End Sub

Comment: Thanks I tried copying this but when I change the value in column E it gives me the error Compile error: Expected End Sub. When column C changes, nothing happens.

Comment: You need to close the subroutine with "End Sub." The editing wasn't quite finished, as you can see above; the "End Sub" is not within the code box.

Answer (score 1):

The **Calculate** event triggers before the **Change** event. You must use the Calculate and Change events to solve your problem.

Assuming **column C** must contain the mentioned formula. Observing your given formula, we can say it is linked to **column A**.

***Step 1***: Right-click on the sheet name tab => Click on **View Code** => Paste the following => Save.

```
Public lastChangedCell As Range
Public lastChangedCellRow As Long
Public ClearCell As Boolean

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Columns("A")) Is Nothing And ClearCell = True Then

        Set lastChangedCell = Target

        lastChangedCellRow = lastChangedCell.Row
        Me.Range("E" & lastChangedCellRow).ClearContents

        ClearCell = False

    End If

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

    ClearCell = True

End Sub
```

**Note**: Keep the workbook named **Control** open.

***Step 2***: Now, return to the intended sheet, make changes and see the output like the following **GIF**.
[image]
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

When the cell values change by formulas, the **Change** event will not trigger. Perhaps you should consider using the **Calculate** event regarding your problem.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
End Sub
```

Comment: Could you explain how to do this? I really have no experience with VBA

Comment: For sure. Please see my following answer.